# Postgres JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS with counter or index value

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Suppose I have this `order` table, where the `widgets` column is a `jsonb` array:

| order_no | widgets |
| --- | --- |
| 50 | [a,b,c] |
| 51 | [d,e,f] |

```sql
select
  order_no,
  jsonb_array_elements_text(widgets) widget
from order;
```

| order_no | widget |
| --- | --- |
| 50 | a |
| 50 | b |
| 50 | c |
| 51 | d |
| 51 | e |
| 51 | f |

Is there a way to get the query to include an increment/counter for each jsonb array element from the record in `order`? (the example is zero-based, but find with 1-based...)

| order_no | widget | item_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | a | 0 |
| 50 | b | 1 |
| 50 | c | 2 |
| 51 | d | 0 |
| 51 | e | 1 |
| 51 | f | 2 |

Comment: That's what `WITH ORDINALITY` is for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move the function call to the FROM, and then add WITH ORDINALITY.  It is 1 based, not 0 based, so you would have to subtract 1.

```
select order_no, value as widget, ordinality-1 as item_no
from "order", jsonb_array_elements_text(widgets) with ordinality;
```

You should not use "order" as a table name, as it is a reserved word.  You can do it by putting it in quotes, but it is still a bad idea.

Comment: thanks and good call re the table name -- it was a contrived example just for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the set returning function where it belongs: in the FROM clause. Then you can use the `with ordinality` option:

```
select o.order_no,
       w.*
from "order" o
  cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(widgets) with ordinality as w(widget, idx)
order by o.order_no, w.idx;
```

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for the ROW_NUMBER() window function :)

```
select
  order_no,
  jsonb_array_elements_text(widgets) widget,
  row_number() over(partition by order_no order by order_no) as item_no
from order;
```